# Stange VMWare Fusion Display issue

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

I just updated my Mac OSX server and VMWare started having a strange problem: when a virtual machine is running the display is always black even though the VM is accepting input and working correctly. When I suspend the virtual machines it does display the screen in the preview window and it is show behind the start button.

Both VMs on the computer have the same problem and both have 3D Graphics disabled. One VM is running Bash and the other Gnome and neither have had problems before.

So far I've restarted both VMs and the computer itself.

Any ideas?? Thanks everyone!